# how to configure prettier to format html attributes always in a new-line

Tags: prettier

i was looking at prettier [singleAttributePerLine option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line), which only split html element with more than one attribute.

it there any way to make prettier consistent and always format html attribute in a new line?

for example, from:

```html
<div id="prettier">content</div>
```

to:

```html
<div
  id="prettier">
  content
</div>
```

how to configure prettier to format html element attribute in a new-line always, even if there is a single attribute?

Comment: Did you try additng these two `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'ignore'` and `singleAttributePerLine: true`?

Comment: @mandy8055 i did. it does not do what i desire.